# Getting 401 errors from DirectLine when using botbuilder handoff

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm working on a new bot and attempting to implement human handoff. I am using Directline 3.0 to communicate between a BotFramework-WebChat client and my bot, which is hosted on Azure Bot Service.

My problem is that I'm getting 401 errors from the Directline API when my bot attempts to send a message from user to agent or agent to user.

To explain the issue further, we only really need to discuss the *Watching* state. In the code, customer messages are intercepted via middleware. If the state is determined to be *Watching*, customer messages are routed to both the bot and the watching agent.

The message from bot to user, sent with `session.send('foo')` works fine, but the message from bot to agent, sent like:

```
address = conversation.agent;

// the commented codes makes the whole thing work...
// address.useAuth = true;

agentMessage = new builder.Message()
    .address(address)
    .text(message.text);

bot.send(agentMessage, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

doesn't work unless I add a `useAuth` flag. I found this flag in the ChatConnector.js implementation, and it seems to decide (as you would guess) whether the message uses an authorized request when sending. You can see in my above code that I can set this flag myself, but it's a hacky solution and it seems to be circumventing the real application logic.

This whole thing feels wrong, and I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't figure out how to make these requests work without setting `useAuth` directly.

Here's a bit of the relevant code from my handoff client. I've removed a bit of code from below to only focus on messages from the customer while the conversation is in the *Waiting* state.

```
/* this middleware is used by the bot */
public routingMiddleware(bot: builder.UniversalBot) {
    return {
        //intercepts messages from user to bot
        botbuilder: (session: builder.Session, next: Function) => {
            // Pass incoming messages to routing method
            if (session.message.type === 'message') {
                this.routeMessage(session, bot, next);
            } else {
                // allow messages of non 'message' type through
                next();
            }
        }
    }
}

private routeMessage(session: builder.Session, bot: builder.UniversalBot, next: Function) {
    this.routeCustomerMessage(session, bot, next);
}

private async routeCustomerMessage(session: builder.Session, bot:builder.UniversalBot, next: Function) {
    const message = session.message;
    let agentMessage: builder.Message;
    let address: any;

    // method will either return existing conversation or a newly created conversation if this is first time we've heard from customer
    const conversation = await this.getConversation({ customerConversationId: message.address.conversation.id }, session);

    // log the user's message to persistent storage
    await this.addToTranscript({ customerConversationId: conversation.customer.conversation.id }, message, session);

    switch (conversation.state) {
        case ConversationState.Watch:
            address = conversation.agent;

            // the commented codes makes the whole thing work...
            // address.useAuth = true;

            agentMessage = new builder.Message()
                .address(address)
                .text(message.text);

            bot.send(agentMessage, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
            return next();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to be stuck using `useAuth` flag at the moment. There's a few public examples out there, but even the Node Payment Bot in the documentation uses the flag to authenticate the request: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/78af7ceae19e9cea463d2fc4c04537cfd1e49494/Node/sample-payments/app.js. Hopefully someone from MS will be along shortly to answer in more detail.